# After windows install, Fedora no longer boots up. Getting error: file '/vmlinuz' not found found. How do I fix the boot?

Tags: fedora, boot, grub2

I had to install Windows 10. Because I was having difficulty with the install, I unplugged the first two of my drives (which had Fedora data). So with only one hard drive plugged in, I was able to get Windows successfully installed.

Now, I have plugged all of my drives in. I'm able to get Windows to boot up properly, but Fedora is no longer booting up.

This is the error when I select Fedora from the grub:

> error: no such device: 3b9c12dc-6ed0-4e2f-a28b-3e0931ccfea2
>
> error: file'/vmlinuz-4.13.9-300.fc27.x86_64' not found.
>
> error: you need to load the kernel first.

So, I googled around and found this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904179/error-file-vmlinuz-4-4-0-59-generic-not-found-you-need-to-load-the-kernel-f), but to be honest, I didn't really understand the answer completely. Either way, I pressed `c` for the grub command line. When I type in `ls` on the command line, I see this:

> (lvm/fedora_hdd-swap) (lvm/fedora_sdd-root) (lvm/fedora_sdd-home) (hd0) (hd0,gpt4) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1) (hd1) (hd1,gpt12) (hd1,gpt11) (hd2) (hd3) (hd3,gpt4) (hd3,gpt3) (hd3,gpt2) (hd3,gpt1)

Now, when I type in `ls (lvm/fedora_hdd-root)/`, I do see all the necessary linux files such as /boot, /etc, etc. So my files are safe and sound, I just need to configure the grub properly, I'm assuming?

When I go back to the grub, and type `e` to edit the Fedora listing, I see this:

```
getparams 'Fedora (4.13.9-300.fc27.x86_64) 27 (Workstation Edition)
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=achi0,gpt2 3b9c12dc-6ed0-4e2f-a28b-3e0931ccfea2
    else
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3b9c12dc-6ed0-4e2f-a28b-3e0931ccfea2
    fi
```

I think based on what I see in the grub command line, I'm supposed to edit the listing accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GRUB does not really care about your Linux root partition; only the Linux kernel cares about that. What GRUB wants to find is the partition that contains the `/boot` filesystem. For various reasons GRUB calls it the "GRUB root filesystem".

The kernel pathname in the error message `error: file '/vmlinuz-4.13.9-300.fc27.x86_64' not found` did not have `/boot` prefixed to it. That tells me your `/boot` was probably a separate filesystem, and the `set root='hd0,gpt2'` line in the GRUB configuration for booting Fedora tells me that it used to be the second partition on some GPT-partitioned disk at some point in time.

If you type `ls (lvm/fedora_hdd-root)/boot/`, you'll probably find it is just an empty directory. It serves as the mount point for the actual `/boot` filesystem.

There is also the filesystem UUID, but the error message `error: no such device: 3b9c12dc-6ed0-4e2f-a28b-3e0931ccfea2` indicates it cannot be found.

My guess is that in the best case, the drive detection order may have changed, and what used to be `hd0,gpt2` could now be `hd3,gpt2`.

In the worst case, your `/boot` partition actually was on the disk you installed Windows 10 to, and the Windows installation overwrote that partition. But a `/boot` partition is relatively easy to replace: you'll need to boot into rescue mode from a Fedora installation media, using the boot menu option `Troubleshooting` -> `Rescue a Fedora system`, or the `inst.rescue` boot option.

Once the rescue mode has started up, it should offer you a command prompt. If all goes well, your Fedora system should already be mounted for you under `/mnt/sysimage`. So first use a `chroot /mnt/sysimage` command, so you won't have to prefix `/mnt/sysimage` to all the pathnames, and you will be able to use the normal package management tools.

Now you can either create a new `/boot` partition and mount it, or - since your GRUB can apparently read LVM logical volumes - just reinstall the contents that should be in the `/boot` filesystem into the `/boot` directory of your root filesystem.

Since you apparently are using an UEFI-based system (as all your partitions are GPT type), that means just creating an empty directory at `/boot/efi` if it does not already exist (to act as a mount point for the EFI System Partition, or ESP), running `mount /boot/efi`, verifying that the settings in `/etc/default/grub` match the current configuration, and re-installing the latest kernel package using `rpm --reinstall`.

The kernel package contains the `/vmlinuz-*` file, and the package installation process will automatically create an appropriate initramfs file for it. Once that is done, all the essential files that must be in `/boot` should now be recovered. The kernel package reinstallation process should even update the actual GRUB configuration file for you.

Note that GRUB has two configuration files: the simplified one in `/etc/default/grub`, and the auto-generated actual configuration file, which is located in `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` on UEFI systems. If you update the former after re-installing the kernel package, you can manually trigger the update of the latter file with this command:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
So before I installed Windows, I had two drives (ssd and hdd). I used both of them for fedora. Then for Windows, I bought a separate drive, unplugged the other two drives, and then installed Windows. So as far as Windows is concerned, it does not know about the other two drives at all. This leads me to believe that the `/boot` partition was not overwritten by Windows as was stated in your worst case scenario.
Keeping that in mind, before I even try the boot rescue mode, should I try replacing `set root='hd0,gpt2'` with other partitions (trial and error)? Is that safe?

Comment: Anything you in GRUB by pressing `e` to edit the current boot configuration will be non-persistent, and so will be safe: if you get it wrong, just reboot and try again. If you find the correct setting, remember it and either make the same change to `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` manually, or use `grub2-mkconfig` to generate a new configuration.